# SQL Remove \n and parse JSON in one command

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The data is formatted like so:

Query:

```
select X from DB
```

Output:

```
{\n  "_id": "5a7e4b7cf36d3920dd24bc0e",\n  "price": 0,\n  "name": "XXX"\n}
```

What I'm trying to do is both remove the \n characters and parse the response itself. I'd like to grab **just the _id** field.

My current query is not quite right:

**Step 1:** Remove the \n characters:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(X, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') from DB
```

Output:

```
{"_id": "5a7e4b7cf36d3920dd24bc0e", "price": 0,"name": "XXX"}
```

**Question: How can I tweak this query to parse the JSON and return the _id field all at once?** I've tried this with no luck:

```
SELECT PARSE_JSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(X, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')) from DB
```

^ This query just outputs the same as the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT X:_id FROM DB
```